# the meaning of "go as so far to"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Though he did come to see Garp as family, he did not approve of his violent behavior towards Luffy. At one point he warned him to stop abusing Luffy **going as so far to** call him an "old piece of crap". Garp, who had promised to make fine Marines out of the two brothers, was furious when he discovered that Ace had gone ahead to become a pirate instead.

What does "go as so far to" in the second line mean? Does it mean he warned him to stop abusing Luffy and was so upset about it to the point that he called him an "old piece of crap"?

Comment: Bad English in that anime fan-fic writing. Should be  'going so far as to...' and there should be a comma after 'Luffy'.

Comment: I was going to ask if the phrase in the original post was the other way of saying 'go so far as to' or a typo. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: Much Anime and other fan-fiction is written either by non-native speakers, or native speakers whose education is poor or not yet complete, and is often not checked for grammar, spelling, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means the protagonist had enough with Garp's abusing of Luffy, and **went as far as to** call him names.

> According to [Dictionary.com - go so far as to](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-so-far-as-to):
>
> > Proceed to the point of doing something
> >
> > - I wouldn't go so far as to call him incompetent, but he does need supervision.
> > - Would she go as far as to sell the house before she's found another?